# How to store hierarchical structure data SQL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem about storing hierarchical data to database.
Assume I have a panel A which contains 4 fields. Admin can create rule to validate for panel A.

Example:
**Field A with Field B → Rule 1 (OR)

Field C with Field D → Rule 2 (AND)

Rule 1 with Rule 2 → Rule 3 (AND)**

Hierarchical data can show below image:

[image]

Result will return false if field does not input
If user only input Field A and Field C,we have expressions
Rule 1: true or false → true
Rule 2: true and false → false
Rule 3: Rule 1 and Rule 2 → false
Because Rule 3 is root so user can not save data to database

Now I'm creating demo by inputing data in SQL below data:

[image]

I can load in code C# successfully but if I save from form to database, I don't know how to save because rule ID is auto increment number.

Comment: Links don't work, use imgur.com

Comment: i have just edited links

Answer (score 0):

There is built-in hierarchyid data type in sql server, it is same thing you are looking for.
for more detail see below links:-

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manisblog/archive/2007/08/17/sql-server-2008-hierarchyid.aspx